# Laravel how to render into fusion charts by day based on the query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, laravel

Basically i want to render my chart as like this

[image]

In fusioncharts said, my data should be like this in order to render

```
  "data": [{
          "label": "January 21, 2020",
          "value": "3"
        },
        {
          "label": "January 22, 2020",
          "value": "1"
        },
         {
          "label": "January 23, 2020",
          "value": "2"
        },
         {
          "label": "January 24, 2020",
          "value": "1"
        },
```

But in my query like this

```
  public function getGraph(){
        $ext = \DB::table('checkers')
                ->where('remarks_id',2)
                ->join('schedules','schedules.id','=','checkers.schedule_id')
                ->join('teachers','schedules.teacher_id','=','teachers.id')
                ->where('schedules.teacher_id',1)
                ->count();

        $date = \DB::table('checkers')
                ->where('remarks_id',2)
                ->select(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(checkers.created_at, '%M %d, %Y') date "))
                ->join('schedules','schedules.id','=','checkers.schedule_id')
                ->join('teachers','schedules.teacher_id','=','teachers.id')
                ->get();        

        return response()->json([
            'count' => $ext,
            'date' => $date
        ]);
    }
```

Note `remarks_id = 2` and `teacher_id` is based on the teacher I select.

The result is like this

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "date": [
    {
      "date": "January 21, 2020"
    },
    {
      "date": "January 23, 2020"
    }
  ]
}
```

It says `count : 1` but the correct value is two because there are two dates indicated as absent.

here is my tables included
checkers

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+---------------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| id | schedule_id | user_id | remarks_id | status                    | created_at          | updated_at | deleted_at |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+---------------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 |       1 |          2 | Round 1 and 2 For sched 1 | 2020-01-21 00:00:00 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  5 |           3 |       1 |          9 | Schedule 3                | 2020-01-22 00:00:00 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  6 |           2 |       1 |          2 | Schedule 2                | 2020-01-23 00:00:00 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+---------------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+

When I was going to get the absent, i used `created_at` column for displaying the dates, I used `DATE_FORMAT(created_at)` in order to format it.
```

Schedules

```
+----+-----------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| id | subject_code_id | teacher_id | room_id | school_year | start_time | end_time | day       |
+----+-----------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |               1 |          1 |       1 | 2020        | 10:30 PM   | 12:30 AM | M-T-W-T-F |
|  2 |               2 |          2 |       2 | 2020        | 5:30 PM    | 6:30 PM  | M-T-W-T-F |
|  3 |               3 |          1 |       3 | 2020        | 10:30 PM   | 11:30 AM | SAT       |
+----+-----------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

I just want to graph the absences of the employee per day and counting it i dont know why im getting `count 1` there are two dates so that means `teacher_id = 1` has two absences. as you can see in checkers there is `remarks_id = 2` means absent for `teacher_id = 1` in `schedules`.

the `teacher_id = 1` has two schedules which is `1` and `3` in the `schedules` table .. and you can see in `checkers` there are `schedule_id = 1` and `3` that is for `teacher_id = 1`

How could i make it to display at the line charts? The query seems tricky for me to do. I hope you understand what I mean. And also if the teacher has two schedules and he is absent for the day, his count for that day will be `2` since he got two schedules. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right counting. Your query should return 1 not 2 as you assume. From table `checkers` you are selecting 2 rows with values of field `schedule_id` which is equal to 1 and 2. Then you selected by this field next 2 rows from table Schedules which contain values 1 and 2 of field `teacher_id`. But we have condition that we should select from table `schedules` only rows with value teacher_id = 1 that is why your second select result with field teacher_id = 2 is filtered and you get only one row which satisfies all two `where` conditions.

I assume you have made some errors when added manually test data to tables. That is why you have other result then you have expected.

You can modify your second sql to something like this:

```
->select(\DB::raw("COUNT(checkers.id) `value` "), \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(checkers.created_at, '%M %d, %Y') label "))
```

And don't forget to `group by` and you will get appropriate json for fusioncharts.

Comment: Thanks, I didint notice that! now my problem is how to output this in the graph